# laravel - redirect to GET request after form is submitted

Tags: php, laravel

I have want to submit a form with post request where the method in the controller will redirect to a view.

Controller:

```
//Create quotation
    public function quotation(Request $request){
        
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'parcel_weight' => 'required',
            'parcel_size' => 'required',
            'postcode_pickup' => 'required|postal_code:MY|exists:postcodes,postcode',
            'postcode_delivery' => 'required|postal_code:MY|exists:postcodes,postcode'
        ]);

        //logic to compute the quotation rate for each courier based on the inputs
        //dd($request->all());
        
        return redirect()->route('quotation.show');
       
    }

    //Show quotation
    public function showQuotation(){
        
        return view('orders.quotation');
    }
```

web.php:

```
//Create new order
Route::get('/dashboard/orders','Dashboard\OrderController@index')->name('order.index');

//Generate quotation
Route::post('/dashboard/orders','Dashboard\OrderController@quotation')->name('order.quotation');

//Quotation page
Route::get('/dashboard/orders/quotation','Dashboard\OrderController@showQuotation')->name('quotation.show');
```

This code works fine but in order to hit the `route('quotation.show')`, data must be submitted from the form. If I just copy the URI and paste into the browser `.../dashboard/orders/quotation` then I will still be able to view the page without any input submitted. How do I prevent this?

Edit:

Using `with()` does not seem to work.

```
//Create quotation
    public function quotation(Request $request){
        
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'parcel_weight' => 'required',
            'parcel_size' => 'required',
            'postcode_pickup' => 'required|postal_code:MY|exists:postcodes,postcode',
            'postcode_delivery' => 'required|postal_code:MY|exists:postcodes,postcode'
        ]);

        //logic to compute the quotation rate for each courier based on the inputs
        //dd($request->all());
        
        return redirect()->route('quotation.show')->with(['form','form']);
       
    }

    //Show quotation
    public function showQuotation(){
       
        if(request()->has('form')){
            dd('Data has been submitted');

        }else{

            dd('NO DATA');
        }

            

    }
```

Comment: Use `->with(['something' => 'something'])` on the `redirect()->route()`, and check if `request()->has('something')`. If it doesn't, prevent the action.

Comment: @TimLewis Any other way with helper function to accomplish this?

Comment: Generally,`GET` request should return a `view()`, `POST` requests should return a `redirect()` regardless. If you don't want to be able to access a `GET` request directly from an inserted URL, redirecting from a `POST` using `->with()`, which sets a `session` variable will accomplish that and (to my knowledge) can't easily be spoofed.

Comment: Somehow I tried using  ```->with()``` but it could not be detected by ```request()....```

Comment: @TimLewis I updated my question to show how the code looks like. Even when I submit the form, it still returns no data.

Comment: @TimLewis Still didn't work. Somehow it couldn't detect the request. I even tried ```exists()``` or ```filled()``` but couldn't work.

Comment: Try with `session()->has('form')`. For example: `session()->flash('form', true)`, then `session()->has('form')` is `true`, but `request()->has('form')` is `false`; that was my mistake.

Comment: Okay my bad, ```session()``` does work, I made a mistake of the syntax error in the ```with()```. Post your answer and I'll mark as solved. On a side note, why doesn't ```request()``` able to detect the value?

Comment: `request()` is a different thing than `session()`; I mistook them. You can actually do `request()->session()` (chain them), but it's not correct on `request()`. And I'll add an answer shortly 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent direct navigation to a `GET` request (via entering a URL in your browser's URL bar, for example), then you'll need to add some back-end logic to prevent that. A quick solution is to include a `session` variable on the `redirect()`. This will include it in the session once, where you can then check it and act accordingly.

In the handler for your `POST` method:

```php
return redirect()->route('quotation.show')->with(['submitted' => true]);
```

Then, in the handler for your `GET` method:

```php
if (session()->has('submitted')) {
  return view(...);
} else {
  abort(403); // Unauthorized
  // or
  return redirect('/'); // Return home, etc
}
```

Sidenote: `dd('Access')` and `dd('No Access')` is good for debugging to see if your approach is working.

Edit: `->with()` performs a "Flash", meaning `submitted` will be available for a single request only. If you need this to persist in the session longer (i.e. to facilitate refreshing the page), adjust the code:

```php
session()->put('submitted', true);
return redirect()->route('quotation.show');
```

You'll now be able to refresh the page after being redirected, but you will also be able to navigate away, then manually back and still see your results. It's a give and take solution.

Comment: Thanks. Though there might be a catch with this solution, assuming I submitted my data and proceed to the next page, accidentally refreshing the page(means no form submitted) will throw the abort page.

Comment: As it should; `->with()` performs a "flash", meaning the session value `form` (or `submitted` in my answer) persists for one call. Refreshing the page would be a new call. If you need that to persist for more than a single call, adjust the code. I'll update my answer to handle that 

Comment: Cool. After submitting my request, the session will always be there until I close my browser and it resets right?  Though by design choice, should I keep the session or leave it like the way it was behaving before?

Comment: Essentially, yes. You can configure Laravel to nuke sessions on browser close, or they'll naturally expire based on session lifetime, or if you really wanted to, you could store it in session "forever". The choice is yours on how to handle that, whatever fits your needs!

Comment: Hey man, I was wondering if you have any suggestion on passing multiple data between different post request?  I can't seem to wrap my head around this so I figured to try my luck :).  I made a post about it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292080/laravel-passing-data-from-first-page-to-third-page/68292229

Comment: Looks like that post has the correct approach, but instead of multiple `->with()` calls, a single one with an array like `->with(['one' => 'one', 'two' => 'two'])` (should work the same, is a little cleaner IMO). What isn't work with that?

Comment: Basically, my issue is this. I was suggested to save data in the session and populate them in my blade. Sure that would work, but I cannot access relationship like ```$rate->courier....``` which gives an error. On the other hand, my current approach is to use hidden inputs to passed them back to second POST request but hidden inputs are vulnerable as well. So, I'm kinda stuck here to figure how to tackle this.

Comment: Yeah, "serialization of closures" error I assume? You can't really save models to Session like that. Save something like `rate_id` to session, then retrieve `$rate` from the database via `session()->get('rate_id')`, then you can do `$rate->courier`

Comment: Yeah that serialization error. Hmmm, how would it look like code wise? Because as of now, I might want to pass the image filename as well via relationship as well as courier name to the final booking page. Since the radio button for selecting the courier only be able to pass ```$rate->cost``` to the next request.

Comment: `$rate_ids = Rate::where(...)->pluck('id')`, then `->with(['rate_ids' => $rate_ids, ...])`, then in `showQuotation`, `$rates = Rate::whereIn('id', session()->get('rate_ids'));`. Then you can use `$rate->whatever` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused to the logic. Maybe you can post the answer on that thread?

Comment: Sure, 1 sec, I'll move that over to there.