# laravel - passing data from first page to third page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a booking system where I divided into three steps. First, user can input the parcel weight, postcode,etc and then generate a quotation for couriers rate which brings to the next step.

Second, it shows an a list of rates for the couriers to choose and user have to select one courier and proceed to the next page which is the booking order page.

Thirdly, this page contains a form and some fields such as parcel weight, postcode , etc will be generated as you expected. So basically, I have to pass these data from 1st view all the way to the 3rd view and also the quotation rate selected from the 2nd page to the 3rd page to finalize the booking.

To summarize: parcel page(enter information parcel) -> quotation page(select a courier) -> booking order page(submit order)

web.php:

```
//Create new order
Route::get('/dashboard/orders','Dashboard\OrderController@index')->name('order.index');

//Generate quotation
Route::post('/dashboard/orders/quotation','Dashboard\OrderController@quotation')->name('order.quotation');

//Quotation page
Route::get('/dashboard/orders/quotation','Dashboard\OrderController@showQuotation')->name('quotation.show');



//Booking order page
Route::post('/dashboard/orders/booking','Dashboard\OrderController@createOrder')->name('create.quotation');

//Show booking order page
Route::get('dashboard/orders/booking','Dashboard\OrderController@showBooking')->name('show.booking');
```

OrderController.php:

```
//Create quotation
    public function quotation(Request $request){
        
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'parcel_weight' => 'required',
            'parcel_size' => 'required',
            'postcode_pickup' => 'required|postal_code:MY|exists:postcodes,postcode',
            'postcode_delivery' => 'required|postal_code:MY|exists:postcodes,postcode'
        ]);

        //logic to compute the quotation rate for each courier based on the inputs
        //default - postcode belongs to Penisular Malaysia
        $location_id = 1;

        if((88000<= $request->postcode_delivery) && ($request->postcode_delivery <= 91309) ){
            //check postcode belongs Sabah
            $location_id = 2;
        }

        if((930000<= $request->postcode_delivery) && ($request->postcode_delivery <= 98859) ){
            //check postcode belongs to Sarawak
            $location_id = 2;
        }

        $rates=Rate::where('weight',$request->parcel_weight)->where('location_id',$location_id)->get();
        
        //session()->put('submitted', true);
        return redirect()->route('quotation.show')
                         ->with('rates',$rates)
                         ->with('weight',$request->parcel_weight)
                         ->with('postcode_delivery',$request->postcode_delivery);
       
    }

    //Show quotation
    public function showQuotation(){
       //check if form is submitted
        if(session()->has('rates')){
           
            return view('orders.quotation')->with('rates',session('rates'))
                                           ->with('weight',session('weight'))
                                           ->with('postcode_delivery',session('postcode_delivery'));
        }

            abort(403);
    }

    //Show booking page
    public function createOrder(Request $request){
        //// Should be able to retrieve request from courier rate chosen, the weight of parcel, postcode
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

quotation.blade.php:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="offset-1 col-11">
        <h4 style="font-weight: 700">Regular Order</h4>
        <p>Please select one courier:</p>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('create.quotation')}}">
         @csrf
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($rates as $rate)
            <div class="col-3 col-md-2"> 
                <!-- ISSUE HERE------>
                 <input type="hidden" value="{{$weight}}"> 
                 <img style="height: 60px; width:80px;" src="{{asset($rate->courier->image->path .''.$rate->courier->image->filename)}}" alt="{{$rate->courier->image->filename}}">                     
                 <div>
                    <input type="radio" class="mt-1"   name="courier" value="{{$rate->cost}}">
                    <label for="{{$rate->courier->name}}">RM{{$rate->cost}}</label>        
                </div>        
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="offset-md-3 mt-4">
            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn" style="border-radius: 20px; background:#efcc37;">Book Delivery</button>  
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to retrieve the data this way although I feel it might be overcomplicated of doing it. And,hidden inputs are also vulnerable as well. Is there another way of passing the data from start(1st page) all the way to the end(3rd page) without doing it my way?

How do I save the data(retrieve from 1st) in session so I can retrieve it in the final page?

Comment: Would you consider using session for the data?

Comment: For which data specifically?

Comment: Like, you send a POST request, push input parcel weight, postcode, etc to session, and return the next page that contains second form. Then do the same

Comment: Do you mind demonstrating or post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->with('rates', $rates)` or `session()->push('rates', $rates)` isn't going to be valid for what you need to do here. Since `$rates` is an Eloquent Collection, pushing to `session()` wipes out all ability to search against relationships, like `$rate->relationship->property`. To handle this, pass along IDs and query in your `GET` handler:

In the handler for your `POST` method:

```php
public function quotation(Request $request) {
  // ...

  $rateIds = Rate::where('weight', $request->parcel_weight)
  ->where('location_id', $location_id)
  ->pluck('id');

  return redirect()->route('quotation.show')->with([
    'rate_ids' => $rateIds,
    'weight' => $request->input('parcel_weight'),
    'postcode_delivery' => $request->input('postcode_delivery')
  ]);
}
```

This will return a Collection of `rates.id` columns from your Database. You can then pass this in Storage and query in your `GET` handler:

```php
public function showQuotation(){
  if (!session()->has('rate_ids')) {
    return abort(403);
  }
  
  $rates = Rate::with('courier.image')
  ->whereIn('id', session()->get('rate_ids'))
  ->get();
  
  return view('orders.quotation')->with([
    'rates' => $rates,
    'weight' => session()->get('weight')
    'postcode_delivery' => session()->get('postcode_delivery')
  ]);
}
```

Now in your `orders/quotation.blade.php`, you can do `@foreach ($rates as $rate)`, and `$rate->relationship->property` will work just fine.

Comment: Hang on a second, let me see if it works.

Comment: I tested your solution, although there's no error but it didn't show the correct rate. I have 10 different couriers but it's showing only 5 courier. My rate table is ```id - courier_id - weight - cost - location_id```. I don't think you can query the database like that, since i have courier_id can have 2 rates for 1 kg (east region and west region).

Comment: You'll have to debug that further yourself. Double check that `$rateIds` contains the IDs you're expecting, and if not, fix your query in the `POST` method. This question is not about that query, so try not to modify your requirements to the point of invalidating this answer.

Comment: Got it then. ```session()->get('rate_ids')``` gives me the correct values.

Comment: by the way , why did you use ```whereIn```? Since ```session()->get('rate_ids')``` gives a collection but ```whereIn``` accepts an input of array?

Comment: Collections are essentially arrays with extra functionality :) `Model::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])` and `Model::whereIn('id', collect([1, 2, 3]))` will both return `Model` records for ids 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Gotcha. So far from my debugging, ```session()->get('rate_ids')``` returns a collection of 10 objects with the correct values. So that conforms the query post method is correct. But the ```whereIn``` query returns five objects so I am thinking how to further debug it as it's expected to return 10 objects as well.

Comment: A collection of 10 objects what? Do a `dd(session()->get('rate_ids')->toArray());` for easier debugging. Is it 10 unique IDs? Or something else?

Comment: I did make a ```dd(session()->get('rate_ids')->ttoArray()``` and they are correct values. Here's a screenshot for easier visualization : https://ibb.co/Z8jk0hS

Comment: That's wrong. It should be `[5, 65, 125, 185, ...]` (i.e. all the `"id" => ...` values from that array). Did you miss the `->pluck('id')`? `->whereIn('id', ...)` won't work with that Collection.

Comment: Okay so the pluck id gives me ```#items: array:10 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 61
    2 => 121
    3 => 181
    4 => 241
    5 => 301
    6 => 361
    7 => 421
    8 => 481
    9 => 541
  ]```

Comment: Please start looking into the documentation for Laravel's Collections: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections. `pluck('id')` returns a Collection of `id` columns from your `rates` table. That, in turn, is compatible with `whereIn()`.

Comment: And that is correct; now when you do `Rate::whereIn('id', ...)`, it will return `rates` rows with `id` of 1, 62, 121, 181, 241, 301, 361, 421, 481 and 541.

Comment: Right, so in the query, you also use eager loading :).

Comment: Yes, I included `with('courier.image')` to avoid 20 extra queries when doing `@foreach ($rates as $rate)` followed by `$rate->courier->image->whatever`.

Comment: You're a life saver you know that?

Comment: I have been told that before  Happy to help, as always. Cheers!

Comment: Though before you go, if I want to send the last request to the next view, after selecting my courier (via radio button), how do I pass that ```->image->filename``` without assigning multiple values to radio button?

Comment: Make it a checkbox maybe? Radio buttons are inherently one or none, while checkboxes with the same name can send multiple values. Hard to say on this question. Give it a shot and if you still have problems, you can keep posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

So, you push whatever you need to session on quotation, and use it in your next method.

```
public function quotation(Request $request){
    
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'parcel_weight' => 'required',
        'parcel_size' => 'required',
        'postcode_pickup' => 'required|postal_code:MY|exists:postcodes,postcode',
        'postcode_delivery' => 'required|postal_code:MY|exists:postcodes,postcode'
    ]);

    //logic to compute the quotation rate for each courier based on the inputs
    //default - postcode belongs to Penisular Malaysia
    $location_id = 1;

    if((88000<= $request->postcode_delivery) && ($request->postcode_delivery <= 91309) ){
        //check postcode belongs Sabah
        $location_id = 2;
    }

    if((930000<= $request->postcode_delivery) && ($request->postcode_delivery <= 98859) ){
        //check postcode belongs to Sarawak
        $location_id = 2;
    }

    $rates=Rate::where('weight',$request->parcel_weight)->where('location_id',$location_id)->get();

    Session::push('rates', $rates)
    Session::push('weight', $request->parcel_weight)

    return redirect()->route('quotation.show');
   
}

//Show quotation
public function showQuotation(){

    $rates = Session::get('rates')
    $weight= Session::get('weight')

   //check if form is submitted
    if($rates){
       
        return view('orders.quotation');
    }

        abort(403);
}

//Show booking page
public function createOrder(Request $request){
    // access whatever you need from session
    $rates = Session::get('rates')
    $weight = Session::get('weight ')

    dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: But I already push to session with ```with('weight', session('weight),etc``` In my blade, I retrieve it using ```foreach($rates as $rate)...```

Comment: So, what are you missing there? What else is needed in createOrder() method?

Comment: If you use session, then in blade to populate the data, you have to do it differently I assume. Do I still need to chain ```with()``` ?

Comment: No. You can push something to session, open 5 different pages and same stuff will still be there.

Comment: But based on your answer, why do you still need ```->with('rates',$rates)``` if u already push to session

Comment: You're right, I forgot to remove it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also I believe u can use ```Session``` or ```session()```

Comment: Tried your solution but got a ```Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed```

Answer (score -1):

I have 2 solutions.

1. create a temporary row in table after complete step 1. Then pass the id from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3. After step 3 is complete. then make your is_completed column 1.
2. use sessions. generate a uuid after step 1. Save form data to session. then use the session in 2 and 3.